# How do I find the highly correlated variables with another specific variable?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe containing the number of points scored by various individuals in various events. A total column is then added to this dataframe. Now, how do I calculate the highly correlated variables to the total column?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about "[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and "[how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)". This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds suspiciously like an attempt to get us to do your homework for you, but here's a first stab (the total column is assumed to be the first column, for convenience's sake):

```
sort(sapply(df[,-1], function(x) cor(x,df$total)), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]
```

Comment: sapply(sort(cor(hep_cleanup[c(-1,-9)],hep_cleanup$Total)[,1],decreasing = TRUE), names(df[c(1,2,3)])). I ended up here where I was using sort inside sapply. Thanks anyways.

Comment: names(sort(cor(hep_cleanup[c(-1,-9)],hep_cleanup$Total)[,1],decreasing = TRUE))[1:3]. I was able to get the answer without the use of sapply too. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, of course you can. I thought you WANTED to use sapply because that was your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is you need to shape the results of your `cor` output. Melt is your solution.

If you don't want to do the tidyverse solution, use `reshape::melt.`

```
require(dplyr) # for pipe notation and melt
n=1000
set.seed(15)
a=rnorm(n,0)
b=0.5*a                      +rnorm(n,0,.05)
c1=2*a   - 3*b               +rnorm(n,0,0.03)
d=-30*a    +40*b     +50*c1  +rnorm(n,0.01)
e=5*a -             2 * c    + rnorm(n,0,.1)
tot=sum(a,b,c,d,e)
```

That was the reprex, now for the solution

```r
ans=k %>% cor %>%  # correlation matrix
          melt %>%  # convert to a 3 column format (var1,var2,correlation)
          filter(X1=='tot' & X2!='tot') %>% # remove uneeded (tot,tot) row
          arrange(-value)  %>% # sort descending
```

The output is as follows - from here,  you should have no trouble picking off the top 3.

```
|X1  |X2 |     value|
|:---|:--|---------:|
|tot |c1 | 0.9865469|
|tot |d  | 0.9827573|
|tot |a  | 0.9574199|
|tot |b  | 0.9301658|
|tot |e  | 0.7065238|
```